# Mobx React Return Store without Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I am trying to build a function where I can switch languages in my store and use different json files based on return value from a hook.

Here is my store:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { action, computed, makeObservable, observable } from 'mobx';
import { makePersistable } from 'mobx-persist-store';
import { IAppConfig } from '../models/IAppConfig';
import { LanguageType } from '../models/IAppConfig';
import { ILanguage } from '../models/ILanguage';

class AppConfig {
  appConfig: IAppConfig = {
    language: {
      id: 0,
      lang: LanguageType.ru,
      title: 'RU'
    }
  };

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      appConfig: observable,
      changeLang: action,
      language: computed
    });
    makePersistable(this, {
      name: 'AppConfig',
      storage: AsyncStorage,
      expireIn: 86400000,
      properties: ['appConfig']
    });
  }

  changeLang(lang: ILanguage) {
    this.appConfig.language = lang;
  }

  get language() {
    return this.appConfig.language;
  }
}

export const configStore = new AppConfig();
```

here is the screen component:

```
function ProfileScreen() {
  const { TEXT } = useComponent();

  const setLangRu = () => {
    const lang: ILanguage = { id: 0, lang: LanguageType.ru, title: 'russian' };
    configStore.changeLang(lang);
  };

  const setLangEn = () => {
    const lang: ILanguage = {id: 1,lang: LanguageType.en,title: 'english'};
    configStore.changeLang(lang);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{TEXT.HOME.HELLO}</Text>
      <Observer>
        {() => <Text>language is {configStore.language.title}</Text>}
      </Observer>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <BouncedTouchable style={styles.button} onPress={() => setLangRu()}>
          <Text>RU</Text>
        </BouncedTouchable>
        <BouncedTouchable style={styles.button} onPress={() => setLangEn()}>
          <Text>EN</Text>
        </BouncedTouchable>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

and the useText hook which returns dictionary:

```
import { LanguageType } from '../models/IAppConfig';
import { en } from '../config/lang/en';
import { ru } from '../config/lang/ru';
import { configStore } from '../store/AppConfig';

const useText = () => {
  const locale = configStore.language.lang;

  switch (locale) {
    case LanguageType.en:
      return en;
    case LanguageType.ru:
      return ru;
    default:
      return ru;
  }
};

export default useText;
```

The problem is that it is not reactive: the changes in `useText`'s locale variable are not computed reactively (after refresh everything is ok). I have tried using this:

```
const locale = useObserver(() => configStore.language.lang);
```

but it says that `useObserver` is deprecated (even though everything works fine). I don't want to wrap the whole screen in observer so what should I do to get react store in `locale`?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a hook that returns my state.

useSelector hook:

```
import { autorun } from 'mobx';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function useSelector(select: any) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(select);
  useEffect(() => autorun(() => setSelected(select())), []);
  return selected;
}
```

In any component call your store (just like Redux), the example here is the one with the question above:

```
const locale: LanguageType = useSelector(() => AppConfig.language.lang);
```

now if I change the locale in any of my screen, the language changes automatically without restarting the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize your view component, then you can create two components or try to [dereference values later](https://dereference%20values%20late).

So if you stick with [the first approach](https://%3CText%3Elanguage%20is%20%7BconfigStore.language.title%7D%3C/Text%3E), then your component with `language.title` would like this:

```
const MyComponent = observer(({ language }) => (
    <div>
        <Text>language is {language.title}</Text>
    </div>
))
```

Another way is to create generic function which takes a parameter to show data. [The code would like that](https://const%20GenericNameDisplayer%20=%20observer((%7B%20getName%20%7D)%20=%3E%20%3CDisplayName%20name=%7BgetName()%7D%20/%3E)):

```
const GenericDisplayer = observer(({ getName }) => <DisplayName name={getName()} />)
```

and then use in your application:

```
const YourComponent = ({ language }) => (
    <>
        <GenericDisplayer getName={() => person.name} />
    </>
)
```